# Changing Character set to Arabic In Oracle

Tags: oracle

Kindly guide me how to change the character set to Arabic in Oracle .
please mention the steps that i need to follow, regrading it.

Comment: Consider to set Unicode (AL32UTF8) in your database. Then you will never have to be concerned again.

Answer (score 0):

go to start>run type regedit and then look for by pressing h key in keyboard hkey local machine  and software and oracl dev home and look for nls_lang change it  to AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256

Answer (score -1):

Check this link for step by step instructions: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch10.htm#1009904

```
STARTUP MOUNT;
ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
ALTER SYSTEM SET JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES=0;
ALTER SYSTEM SET AQ_TM_PROCESSES=0;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET AR8ISO8859P6;
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE; -- or SHUTDOWN NORMAL; 
STARTUP;
```

Comment: Command `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ...` is de-supported since Oracle 10R1, you may destroy your database (see example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224015/oracle-11g-xe-greek-character-set-not-displaying). However, if the old character set is `US7ASCII` then this approach may work exceptionally.