# Oracle 11g XE greek character set not displaying

Tags: php, oracle, character-encoding, pdo, oracle11g

I used an Oracle 11g EE to create my database and access it through PHP using PDO, and all was working good. But i had to change to 11g XE because i wanted to use it freely inside my company. Now, greek characters won't display on PHP (i get �������� instead). I tried to change the character set with :

```
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
alter system enable restricted session;
alter system set job_queue_processes=0;
alter database open;
alter database character set internal_use EL8MSWIN1253;
shutdown immediate;
startup;
```

But i ended up corrupting the CLOBs.

Now, after reverting to the last known good backup i am trying to use CSSCAN but i cannot find it inside my bin folder or anywhere to download.

Any thoughts on this??

I really need to make it work..

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch11charsetmig.htm

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 11g XE (Express Edition) is a free version of Oracle database software but has a few limitations compared to the Enterprise Edition (EE), including support for character set conversion.

First, it's worth mentioning that changing the character set directly in a live database as you attempted, especially when it's a production database, is generally not recommended, because it could lead to data corruption (as you found out with your CLOBs). In your case, it might be better to export your data, create a new database with the desired character set, and then import your data into the new database.

As for CSSCAN (Character Set Scanner), it's not available in Oracle XE. The CSSCAN tool is used to identify possible data loss or data truncation before changing the database character set, and it's only included in the Enterprise Edition.

You might try the following steps to resolve your issue:

Ensure Database and PHP Character Sets are Matching: First, check that the database's character set is compatible with the Greek characters you are trying to display. You can check this by running the following SQL command in your Oracle database:

```
SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

Make sure the character set supports Greek characters (AL32UTF8 would be a good option). If it doesn't, you might need to recreate the database with a supporting character set.

Set Connection Character Set in PHP: When connecting to your Oracle database through PHP, ensure you're setting the correct character set for the connection. In your PDO connection string, you can specify the character set like this:

```
$conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=YOURDB;charset=AL32UTF8", "username", "password");
```

Make sure to replace 'YOURDB', 'username', and 'password' with your actual database name, username, and password.

Export/Import Database: If your database character set doesn't support Greek characters, and it's feasible, you could export your database, create a new database with a character set that does support Greek characters (like AL32UTF8), and then import your data into the new database. Note that this process can be time-consuming and requires careful planning.

In case of PHP file encoding issues, ensure your PHP files are encoded in UTF-8 without BOM. You can check this in your text editor or IDE settings.

**Remember**, before performing any major operation like export/import, always take a backup of your database.