# setting NLS_LANG only for SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have `NLS_LANG` set in the registry for my local language.
The CMD is not able to display the characters of my local language so i see jibrish. 
i'm talking about prompts from the client and not actual data, error messages for example.

```
SQL> conn scott/tiger
ετσß°.
```

I need to keep the client's setting to the local NLS because other programs are dependent on it.

I've tried adding `$set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252` in the glogin but obviously it's not working since the script is executed only after sql*Plus had already been started.

My question is , is there any way of setting the `NLS_LANG` to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252`  *only* for SQL*Plus ?

Comment: create a batch file that runs `SET NLS_LANG=..` and then calls sqlplus

Comment: this is what i will eventually do if i wont find a creative solution...

Comment: glogin.sql only affects SQL*Plus. Why do you think it is not working?

Comment: Have you tried "alter session set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252;" in glogin.sql?

Comment: Did you run `chcp 1252` before you start SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 10):

`NLS_LANG` cannot be changed for the session in SQL*Plus. You can only set the langage, territory, numeric characters, etc ...
For example:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'AMERICAN';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';
```

`NLS_LANG` is set as an environment variable, so before running *SqlPlus* use:

**On Windows:**

```
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
```

**On Unix (Solaris and Linux, centos etc)**

```
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [login.sql or glogin.sql](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch2.htm#i1132910) to run arbitrary commands when SQL*Plus starts, so set the appropriate session settings in there

Answer (score 0):

alter session set nls_language='AMERICAN';

will solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I ran into the same issue today

From a windows command prompt run before running sqlplus

```
set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
```

Answer (score -2):

```
set linesize 2000;
select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS; 


SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;

STARTUP MOUNT;

ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;

ALTER SYSTEM SET JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES=0;

ALTER SYSTEM SET AQ_TM_PROCESSES=0;

ALTER DATABASE OPEN;

ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE  WE8MSWIN1252;
alter database national character set internal_use AL16UTF16;

SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE; 
STARTUP;
```

Comment: You should add some explanation with your answers, which can help others in the future. [answer]

Comment: Command `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ...` is de-supported since Oracle 10R1, you may destroy your database (see example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224015/oracle-11g-xe-greek-character-set-not-displaying). However, if the old character set is `US7ASCII` then this approach may work exceptionally.