# What is 'nsl' character in Oracle db?

Tags: oracle

I was reading an instruction manual and it was mentioned to check the **nsl** character set. Can someone please tell me what is '**NSL**' character and why do we need to set '**NSL**' character in DB?

Comment: Is that Oracle?  Please document which DBMS it is that you're using (edit your question; add the appropriate tag).  I don't think [AcronymFinder](https://acronymfinder.com/NSL.html) really knows what it is for, though it is usually pretty good.  I doubt that it is Nicaraguan Sign Language, for example.  Could it be a typo for NLS?  That would stand for National Language Support.

Comment: I think you mean NLS, short for **N**ational **L**anguage **S**upport. See Oracle's doc about it for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A84870_01/doc/server.816/a76966/ch1.htm

Answer (score -1):

When your computer process characters, they use numeric codes instead of the graphical representation of the character. For example, when the database stores the letter A, it actually stores a numeric code that is interpreted by software as the letter. These numeric codes are especially important in a global environment because of the potential need to convert data between different character sets.

Basically we use UTF8 and UTF16 most cases. Refer documentation for further details

Query current setting

```
SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET' ;
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
```

@ Session level

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8ISO8859P1
```

@ DB level

```
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET <new_character_set_name>;
```

Refer:http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch10.htm

Comment: Command `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ...` is de-supported since Oracle 10R1, you may destroy your database (see example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224015/oracle-11g-xe-greek-character-set-not-displaying). However, if the old character set is `US7ASCII` then this approach may work exceptionally.